# How to check whether there is bad sector on an external USB hard disk on OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-lion, usb-storage

How can I check whether there are any bad sectors on an externally connected USB hard disk drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix bad blocks on Mac hard disk](http://superuser.com/questions/148227/fix-bad-blocks-on-mac-hard-disk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Related questions

1. [Fix bad blocks on Mac hard disk](https://superuser.com/q/148227/84988) – includes some non-free and closed source software
2. [What free or open source software can I use with Mac hardware to verify integrity of every block of a disk …?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57869/8546)

It's sometimes inappropriate to use the automatic sector relocation capabilities of a drive, so the question raised by ohho becomes distinctive:

- it's about *discovery*.

### Essentially

If there's a defective sector, then you'll either:

- care about data within that sector; or
- not care

– consider this **before** performing any action that may cause relocation (or remapping or sparing, or whatever you call it).

### Why care?

Whilst [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) 6 is not for Macs, a 2003 page for version 5 is enlightening:

- [GRC | SpinRite Data Recovery Technology](http://www.grc.com/srrecovery.htm) ([highlights](https://diigo.com/0xzxd))

Note the section about auto-relocation and the associated risk of dataloss.

SpinRite aside, fast forward a decade from 2003 to 2013:

- the [unmistakable warning presented by Drive Genius 3](https://superuser.com/a/576380/84988) on a Mac.

---

To the question here …

## How to check whether there is bad sector on a USB harddisk on OS X?

For Mac – for OS X – I don't know of anything as capable and **careful** as SpinRite (nothing to disable auto-relocation).

So, as things stand: to verify the sectors of a disk on USB **with OS X**, we're probably limited to using utilities that **may cause relocation**. I can't estimate the degree of risk of associated dataloss, but **if that risk is acceptable** then I should steer first towards:

- the utilities that are up-voted or recommended in related questions (1) and (2) above.

Hint: what's under related question (1) is more immediately user-friendly.

### S.M.A.R.T.

The OS alone can not use S.M.A.R.T. technologies on drives that are external on buses such as USB 2.0 and FireWire.

Elsewhere there's a wealth of information ( and misunderstanding ;) so I'll focus this part of the answer on just one point:

- getting Apple's OS to work with S.M.A.R.T. technology with **external** USB and FireWire drives.

#### OS X SAT SMART Driver

[kasbert / OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver](https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver) on GitHub:

> … a kernel driver for Mac OS X external USB or FireWire drives.
>   It extends the standard driver behaviour by providing access to drive
>   SMART data. The interface to SMART data is same as with ATA family
>   driver, so most existing applications should work. The driver requires
>   a SAT (SCSI ATA Translation) capable external drive enclosure. …

If you try this KEXT with Lion then – as with any third party kernel extension – proceed with caution.

Answer (score 28):

The OS X built in command `fsck_hfs` has an option `-S` that apparently will check whether there is bad block on a USB hard disk on OS X.

From [the official man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fsck_hfs.8.html)(Update: Bloody hell!  Apple has removed the manpages from its site.):

> **-S** Cause **fsck_hfs** to scan the entire device looking for I/O errors.  It will attempt to map the blocks with errors to names, similar to the **-B** option.

Example:

```
fsck_hfs -fy -S /dev/disk3s11
```

It seems to be doing that when run on partitions *without* bad blocks but I've yet to check/document what it does when there *are* bad blocks.

Update: Warning: fsck_**apfs** can**not** do this; while it also has a -S option, it does NOT cause a scan; it does something else entirely.

Comment: In addition, we can obtain the available disk paths with diskutil list

Comment: Yes.  Or df.  I prefer it's output for this!

Comment: Unmount the disk before using fsck_hfs otherwise it will run in read only mode.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I was about to add it when ...https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353815/weird-se-bug-latest-version-of-answer-not-displaying-or-editing-whats-going?noredirect=1#comment1182571_353815

Comment: But hmm ... best way to unmount it before running the fsck command is to unmount the partition(s) on the drive or the whole thing?

Answer (score 4):

Open the Terminal.app in Applications/Utilities.

Cut and paste this inside to install Brew:
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Install e2fsprogs with brew:
`brew install e2fsprogs`

Type `diskutil list` to find your device (/dev/diskX)

Run `badblocks` on your device: (replace the X with your device number)

`/usr/local/Cellar/e2fsprogs/1.44.3/sbin/badblocks -v /dev/diskX`

Comment: You might want to adjust with your version number (1.44.3 here) in the line: '/usr/local/Cellar/e2fsprogs/1.44.3/sbin/badblocks -v /dev/diskX'

Comment: On macOS High Sierra 10.13.6: `Operation not permitted while trying to determine device size` (with/without sudo)

Comment: Could it be linked to the SIP protection? http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the filesystem on the drive you could run

```
fsck_msdos /dev/disk1s1
```

This would check an FAT FS. Maybe that's what you want? Possible commands are:

```
fsck_cs
fsck_exfat
fsck_hfs
fsck_msdos
fsck_udf
```

Comment: These commands check (and optionally repair) the volume data structures, they don't scan the disk for readability/writability of the disk surface.

Comment: `fsck_hfs -S` scans the entire filesystem contents and maps blocks with I/O errors to names.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to really know is to write to each sector and read it back to see if you get the same thing back, checking for errors on the way.

`badblocks` under Linux does this.  `badblocks` has a nondestructive read/write test mode.

Under Windows, I believe if you invoke `chkdsk` with the `/F`, `/B`, and `/R` options it will test each sector for bad sectors.  It is also non-destructive but I'm not sure if it actually writes to each sector to test.

[This Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/338067/equivalent-of-badblocks-on-windows-or-dos) suggests that SpinRite 6 may also do the same thing but I haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

Let me advise you in what order you should proceed if you suspect/know you have bad sectors:

1) Make a copy of your entire partition to another device using dd (look up your partition name using `df`). This might take a while, maybe more than a day on a USB2 disk for 400Gb. `bs=` speeds it up (factor 5 or more), `sync` fills input blocks with zeroes if there were any read errors.

```
dd if=/dev/disk3s8 of=/dev/disk4s9 bs=1024k conv=noerror,sync
```

2) Then check if it actually worked, not only the folder structure but also open the content.

3) If it didn't, try to copy the content of your partition on a file level.

```
cp -Rp /Volumes/<source>/ /Volumes/<destination>/
```

4) Only now, that you have tried to save as much as you can without touching the filesystem, run a check on the partition. `-f` option will force even if it appears ok, `-S` scans for bad blocks. This operation is not guaranteed to be non-destrictive, but it might save your disk.

```
fsck_hfs -fS /dev/disk3s8
```